# How to access cookies in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

What's the AngularJS way to access cookies?  I've seen references to both a service and a module for cookies, but no examples.

Is there, or is there not an AngularJS canonical approach?

Comment: The great thing about angularjs is because of the dependency injectiong aspect of it, you can mock out things like ngCookies for unit testing. Thanks for putting in your steps.

Comment: @DanDoyon I am trying to impelement same thing but in app.js inside config. but I am getting "Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $cookies " any clue.

Comment: @sutikshan-dubey just seeing your question, can you provide code sample?

Comment: @DanDoyon Thanks. cookies didn't solve my pupose, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624181/angularjs-how-to-set-expiration-date-for-cookie-in-angularjs I fixed it using web-storage. This helped me alot - http://people.opera.com/shwetankd/external/demos/webstorage_demo.htm

Comment: This doesn't work.  Does anyone have a working Fiddle of this?

Comment: please post the answer as an *answer* instead of embedding it in the question.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

This answer has been updated to reflect latest stable angularjs version. One important note is that `$cookieStore` is a thin wrapper surrounding `$cookies`. They are pretty much the same in that they only work with session cookies. Although, this answers the original question, there are other solutions you may wish to consider such as using localstorage, or jquery.cookie plugin (which would give you more fine-grained control and do serverside cookies. Of course doing so in angularjs means you probably would want to wrap them in a service and use `$scope.apply` to notify angular of changes to models (in some cases).

One other note and that is that there is a slight difference between the two when pulling data out depending on if you used `$cookie` to store value or `$cookieStore`. Of course, you'd really want to use one or the other.

In addition to adding reference to the js file you need to inject `ngCookies` into your app definition such as:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
```

you should then be good to go.

Here is a functional minimal example, where I show that `cookieStore` is a thin wrapper around cookies:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">

  <h3>Cookies</h3>
  <pre>{{usingCookies|json}}</pre>
  <h3>Cookie Store</h3>
  <pre>{{usingCookieStore|json}}</pre>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
    app.controller('MyController',['$scope','$cookies','$cookieStore', 
                       function($scope,$cookies,$cookieStore) {
      var someSessionObj = { 'innerObj' : 'somesessioncookievalue'};

    $cookies.dotobject = someSessionObj;
    $scope.usingCookies = { 'cookies.dotobject' : $cookies.dotobject, "cookieStore.get" : $cookieStore.get('dotobject') };

    $cookieStore.put('obj', someSessionObj);
    $scope.usingCookieStore = { "cookieStore.get" : $cookieStore.get('obj'), 'cookies.dotobject' : $cookies.obj, };
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

The steps are:

1. include `angular.js`
2. include `angular-cookies.js`
3. inject `ngCookies` into your app module (and make sure you reference that module in the `ng-app` attribute)
4. add a `$cookies` or `$cookieStore` parameter to the controller
5. access the cookie as a member variable using the dot (.) operator
   -- OR --
6. access `cookieStore` using put/get methods

Comment: This answer no longer works, you need to use $cookieStore instead as described in another answer.

Comment: Thanks @Bill, you are probably correct, with 1.2 things have most likely changed. I'll updated it.

Comment: I updated the answer and @Bill $cookieStore is probably easier to use but $cookies still works just a little differently

Comment: @DanDoyon : could you please let me know more about Angular JS cookie creation? I got blocked with this one.

Comment: Does that really create a browser cookie? I've tried to use ngCookie and I can't see any new cookie created on the browser. Or is it because I'm not on a server ?

Comment: I think there are issues when using localhost and cookies). If you use your machine name instead of localhost you may have better success.

Comment: Use $cookies, [$cookieStore is now deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)

Comment: Since this answer mentions jquery.cookie, I though it would be useful to write an answer specifically on how to integrate it with Angular (now that it doesn't need jQuery anymore). You can see the answer [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33058901/1400037).

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but there are many errors in the sample code.

Answer (score 71):

This is how you can set and get cookie values. This is what I was originally looking for when I found this question.

Note we use `$cookieStore` instead of `$cookies`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc10/angular-1.0.0rc10.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc10/angular-cookies-1.0.0rc10.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
    function CookieCtrl($scope, $cookieStore) {
      $scope.lastVal = $cookieStore.get('tab');

      $scope.changeTab = function(tabName){
          $scope.lastVal = tabName;
          $cookieStore.put('tab', tabName);
      };
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="CookieCtrl">
    <!-- ... -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 48):

Angular **deprecated** `$cookieStore` in version 1.4.x, so use `$cookies` instead if you are using latest version of angular. Syntax remain same for `$cookieStore` & `$cookies`:

```
$cookies.put("key", "value"); 
var value = $cookies.get("key");
```

See the [Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) for an API overview. Mind also that the cookie service has been enhanced with some new important features like setting expiration (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28854854/1446845)) and domain (see [CookiesProvider Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider#defaults)).

Note that, in version 1.3.x or below, $cookies has a different syntax than above:

```
$cookies.key = "value";
var value = $cookies.value;
```

Also if you are using bower, make sure to type your package name correctly:

```
bower install angular-cookies@X.Y.Z
```

where X.Y.Z is the AngularJS version you are running. 
There's another package in bower "angular-cookie"(without the 's') which is not the official angular package.

Answer (score 14):

FYI, I put together a JSFiddle of this using the `$cookieStore`, two controllers, a `$rootScope`, and AngularjS 1.0.6. It's on JSFifddle as http://jsfiddle.net/krimple/9dSb2/ as a base if you're messing around with this...

The gist of it is:

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

myApp.controller('CookieCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $cookieStore) {
    $scope.bump = function () {
        var lastVal = $cookieStore.get('lastValue');
        if (!lastVal) {
            $rootScope.lastVal = 1;
        } else {
            $rootScope.lastVal = lastVal + 1;
        }
        $cookieStore.put('lastValue', $rootScope.lastVal);
    }
});

myApp.controller('ShowerCtrl', function () {
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="lastVal" ng-controller="ShowerCtrl">{{ lastVal }}</div>
    <div id="button-holder" ng-controller="CookieCtrl">
        <button ng-click="bump()">Bump!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookieStore](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.%24cookieStore)

Make sure you include http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.0rc10/angular-cookies-1.0.0rc10.js to use it.

Comment: Could you provide a hint about how to access it, or a link to which documentation I need to figure this out?  After including the angular-cookies.js file in my HTML, I added `$cookieStore` to the signature of my controller (i.e. `function AccountCtrl($scope, $cookieStore)`), but then get the following error message: Unknown provider: $cookieStoreProvider <- $cookieStore

Comment: Unfortunately, I've never used it, I just know it exists. Maybe you should ask on the Angular google group for a quicker response. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/angular

Comment: It turns out that `$cookieStore` is apparently mostly intended for client-generated cookies.  To access server-generated cookies, I had to use `$cookies` instead.

Comment: The URL has become out of date — nowadays, angular-cookies- is hosted at Googles CDN, here: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular-cookies.min.js (`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular-cookies.min.js`) See blog post:  http://blog.angularjs.org/2012/07/angularjs-now-hosted-on-google-cdn.html

Comment: While this answer is over a year old and the link is helpful it would be better if you post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Answer (score 4):

Add angular cookie lib : angular-cookies.js

You can use $cookies or $cookieStore parameter to the respective controller

Main controller add this inject 'ngCookies':

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ngCookies']);
```

Use Cookies in your controller like this way:

```
 app.controller('checkoutCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $state, $cookies) { 

//store cookies

 $cookies.putObject('final_total_price', $rootScope.fn_pro_per);

//Get cookies

 $cookies.getObject('final_total_price'); }
```

Comment: correct if you want to response objects +1

Answer (score 3):

AngularJS provides ngCookies module and $cookieStore service to use Browser Cookies.

We need to add angular-cookies.min.js file to use cookie feature.

Here is some method of AngularJS Cookie.

- get(key); // This method returns the value of given cookie key.
- getObject(key); //This method returns the deserialized value of given
  cookie key.
- getAll(); //This method returns a key value object with all the
  cookies.
- put(key, value, [options]); //This method sets a value for given
  cookie key.
- remove(key, [options]); //This method remove given cookie.

**Example**

**Html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.1/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">
{{cookiesUserName}} loves {{cookietechnology}}.
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
myApp.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$cookies', '$cookieStore', '$window', function($scope, $cookies, $cookieStore, $window) {
$cookies.userName = 'Max Joe';
$scope.cookiesUserName = $cookies.userName;
$cookieStore.put('technology', 'Web');
$scope.cookietechnology = $cookieStore.get('technology'); }]);
```

I have Taken reference from http://www.tutsway.com/simple-example-of-cookie-in-angular-js.php.

Answer (score 1):

The original accepted answer mentions [jquery.cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). A few months ago though, it was renamed to [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) and the jQuery dependency removed. One of the reasons was just to make it easy to integrate with other frameworks, like Angular.

Now, if you want to integrate [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) with angular, it is as easy as something like:

```
module.factory( "cookies", function() {
  return Cookies.noConflict();
});
```

And that's it. No jQuery. No ngCookies.

---

You can also create custom instances to handle specific server-side cookies that are written differently. Take for example PHP, that convert the spaces  in the server-side to a plus sign `+` instead of also percent-encode it:

```
module.factory( "phpCookies", function() {
  return Cookies
    .noConflict()
    .withConverter(function( value, name ) {
      return value
            // Decode all characters according to the "encodeURIComponent" spec
            .replace(/(%[0-9A-Z]{2})+/g, decodeURIComponent)
            // Decode the plus sign to spaces
            .replace(/\+/g, ' ')
    });
});
```

The usage for a custom Provider would be something like this:

```
module.service( "customDataStore", [ "phpCookies", function( phpCookies ) {
  this.storeData = function( data ) {
    phpCookies.set( "data", data );
  };
  this.containsStoredData = function() {
    return phpCookies.get( "data" );
  }
}]);
```

I hope this helps anyone.

See detailed info in this issue: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/103

For detailed docs on how to integrate with server-side, see here: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/master/SERVER_SIDE.md

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example using $cookies. After clicking on button, the cookie is saved, and then restored after page is reloaded.

app.html:

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="appController as vm">

    <input type="text" ng-model="vm.food" placeholder="Enter food" />

    <p>My favorite food is {{vm.food}}.</p>

    <p>Open new window, then press Back button.</p>
    <button ng-click="vm.openUrl()">Open</button>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module('app', ['ngCookies'])
    .controller('appController', ['$cookies', '$window', function ($cookies, $window) {
        var vm = this;

        //get cookie
        vm.food = $cookies.get('myFavorite');

        vm.openUrl = function () {
            //save cookie
            $cookies.put('myFavorite', vm.food);
            $window.open("http://www.google.com", "_self");
        };
    }]);

})();
```