# How to set expiration date for cookie in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, cookies, angularjs, session-cookies, angular-cookies

1. We want to store User's Authorization information in cookie which should not be lost upon refresh (F5) of browser.
2. We want to store authorization info in "permanent-cookie" in case user has opted for "Remember Me" check box at the time of log-on.

Comment: For the time being I am using local storage and session storage for this purpose Ref http://people.opera.com/shwetankd/external/demos/webstorage_demo.htm

Answer (score 46):

This is possible in the 1.4.0 build of angular using the `ngCookies` module:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

```
angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
.controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
  // Find tomorrow's date.
  var expireDate = new Date();
  expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate() + 1);
  // Setting a cookie
  $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal', {'expires': expireDate});
}]);
```

Comment: is not very clear from documentation if `{'expires': expireDate});` or ...................................................... `[{'expires': expireDate}]);` format should be used...

Comment: The documentation $cookies.put(key, value, [options])'s [ ] is an annotation for "optional".  It does not mean array!!!  In fact, they said "options" is one object {a:x, b:y, c:z } if you read the documentation again.

Answer (score 32):

For 1.4:
As noted in the comment here and others below, as of 1.4, Angular's native cookie support now provides the ability to edit cookies:

> Due to 38fbe3ee, $cookies will no longer expose properties that
>   represent the current browser cookie values. $cookies no longer polls
>   the browser for changes to the cookies and no longer copies cookie
>   values onto the $cookies object.
>
> This was changed because the polling is expensive and caused issues
>   with the $cookies properties not synchronizing correctly with the
>   actual browser cookie values (The reason the polling was originally
>   added was to allow communication between different tabs, but there are
>   better ways to do this today, for example localStorage.)
>
> The new API on $cookies is as follows:
>
> get put getObject putObject getAll remove You must explictly use the
>   methods above in order to access cookie data. This also means that you
>   can no longer watch the properties on $cookies to detect changes that
>   occur on the browsers cookies.
>
> This feature is generally only needed if a 3rd party library was
>   programmatically changing the cookies at runtime. If you rely on this
>   then you must either write code that can react to the 3rd party
>   library making the changes to cookies or implement your own polling
>   mechanism.

The actual implementation is done via a [$cookiesProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider#defaults) object, which can be passed via the [`put`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies#put) call.

For 1.3 and below:
For those of you who have done your best to avoid having to load jQuery plugins, this appears to be a nice replacement for angular - https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie

Comment: Great solution when using Angular 1.3 or lower.

Answer (score 28):

In Angular v1.4 you can **finally** set some options for the cookies, such as the expiration. Here's a very simple example:

```
var now = new Date(),
    // this will set the expiration to 12 months
    exp = new Date(now.getFullYear()+1, now.getMonth(), now.getDate());

$cookies.put('someToken','blabla',{
  expires: exp
});

var cookie = $cookies.get('someToken');
console.log(cookie); // logs 'blabla'
```

If you check your cookies after running this code you will see that the expiration will be properly set to the cookie named `someToken`.

The object passed as a third param to the `put` function above allows for other options as well, such as setting `path`, `domain` and `secure`. Check [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider#defaults) for an overview.

**PS** - As a side note if you are upgrading mind that `$cookieStore` has been deprecated, so `$cookies` is now the only method to deal with cookies. see [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore)

Answer (score 16):

I would like to present an extra example as some people know the extra duration of the cookies lifetime. ie. They want to set a cookie to last 10 more minutes, or 1 more day.

Usually you already know how much longer the cookie will last in seconds.

```
    var today = new Date();
    var expiresValue = new Date(today);

    //Set 'expires' option in 1 minute
    expiresValue.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 1); 

    //Set 'expires' option in 2 hours
    expiresValue.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 120); 


    //Set 'expires' option in (60 x 60) seconds = 1 hour
    expiresValue.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 3600); 

    //Set 'expires' option in (12 x 60 x 60) = 43200 seconds = 12 hours
    expiresValue.setSeconds(today.getSeconds() + 43200); 

    $cookies.putObject('myCookiesName', 'myCookiesValue',  {'expires' : expiresValue});
```

and you can retrieve it as usual:

```
    var myCookiesValue = $cookies.getObject('myCookiesName');
```

If empty, it returns undefined.

Links;

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp 
 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider#defaults

Comment: Where does `today` come from?

Comment: I tried to make the code nicer and forgot to change all 'now's to today. Now it should be alright.

Comment: I have a question. When I get value from the cookie, should I check its expiration date or `$cookies` automatically returns undefined if the value is expired?

Answer (score 3):

You can go to the angular.js script and change the insert cookie
search for `self.cookies = function(name, value) {`
then u can change the code that adds the cookie for example for 7 days

```
 if (value === undefined) {
    rawDocument.cookie = escape(name) + "=;path=" + cookiePath +
                            ";expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
  } else {
    if (isString(value)) {
        var now = new Date();
        var time = now.getTime();
        time += 24*60*60*1000*7;
        now.setTime(time);
         cookieLength = (rawDocument.cookie = escape(name) + '=' + escape(value) +
                 ';path=' + cookiePath+";expires="+now.toGMTString()).length + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is a little bit old, and already have an accepted answer.

But still a present problem which I 'm struggling with (not regarding jQuery or pure Javascript).

So, after some research I have found this:
https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie

Which delivers an "interface" quite similar to $cookieStore. And permits to configure the expiration date (value and units).

About angular native support on the expiration date with $cookie or $cookieStore, "they" promise updates on this subject on 1.4, look into this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/10530

It will be possible to set expiration date with $cookieStore.put(...), at least they propose that...

**EDIT:** I encountered a "problem" you cannot mix $cookies with angular-cookie modular. So if you set a cookie with`ipCookie(...)` retrieve it with `ipCookie(...)` because with $cookie it will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

As @vincent-briglia [pointed out](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4069), there's a jQuery drop-in that can be used as a workaround until `$cookie` service becomes configurable - [check it out here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/2459#issuecomment-24657403)

Answer (score 0):

You may use https://github.com/ivpusic/angular-cookie

First you need to inject ipCookie into your angular module.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ipCookie']);
```

And now, for example if you want to use it from your controller

```
myApp.controller('cookieController', ['$scope', 'ipCookie', function($scope, ipCookie) {
  // your code here
}]);
```

To create a cookie use

```
ipCookie(key, value);
```

The value supports strings, numbers, booleans, arrays and objects and will be automatically serialized into the cookie.

You can also set some additional options, like number of day when a cookie expires

```
ipCookie(key, value, { expires: 21 });
```