# Expiring cookies with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I need to be able to store some authentication information in a cookie and set an expiration date.

From what I have seen the $cookie and $cookiestore doesn't support this.

Are there any alternatives or is the only way possible to do this on the server side?

I was hoping maybe there is a module that exposes this functionality?

Thanks in advance

Comment: With Angular v1.4 you finally can, check here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28854854/1446845

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a cookie from standard JavaScript from within an Angular Ctrl using window.document.cookie.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie

Example from documentation:

```
document.cookie = "someCookieName=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/";
```

Answer (score 1):

`jquery-cookie` makes this simple. To set a cookie that expires in 30 days,

```
$.cookie('auth', token, 30);
```

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie