# AngularJS $cookies are not persisting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I have a login form with a remember username function. All they do is check the box and the cookie is saved via:

```
$scope.toggleCookie = function()
{
    //-- $scope.remember is the model for the checkbox
    $cookieStore.put('remember', $scope.remember);
    if (!$scope.remember) $cookieStore.remove('email');
}
```

When the user returns to the login page, first I check the `remember` cookie:

```
$scope.remember = ($cookieStore.get('remember') == null || $cookieStore.get('remember') == false) ? false : true;
```

Then I check if there is a value in the `email` cookie:

```
$scope.email = ($cookieStore.get('email') != null) ? $cookieStore.get('email') : '';
```

Now all the above is working fine, I can login with it checked, logout and I can see my username in the input field. If I uncheck it, login and logout, the username is gone.

I can also see this happening in the resources->cookies tab in the chrome dev tools.

I can refresh the page and still, the username is there when checked.

**My issue** is that when I CLOSE chrome, reopen it, all the cookie data is gone. Why is this? I don't have much experience with cookies to begin with.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In Angular v1.4 you can **finally** set some options for the cookies. Here's a very simple example:

```
var now = new $window.Date(),
    // this will set the expiration to 6 months
    exp = new $window.Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth()+6, now.getDate());

$cookies.put('yourCookie','blabla',{
  expires: exp
});

var cookie = $cookies.get('yourCookie');
console.log(cookie); // logs 'blabla'
```

If you check your cookies after running this code you will see that the expiration will be properly set to the cookie named `yourCookie`.

The object passed as a third param to the `put` function above allows for other options as well, such as setting `path`, `domain` and `secure`. Check [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider#defaults) for an overview.

Answer (score 3):

For a cookie to be persistent over browser sessions, the expiration date should be set. Unfortunately, this does not seem to be supported with the angularjs $cookie service. See this post: [AngularJS - How to set expiration date for cookie in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624181/angularjs-how-to-set-expiration-date-for-cookie-in-angularjs)

Comment: I saw that thread after I posted this and figured that had something to do with it. I came across a directive someone made that allowed you to set the expiration. I was hoping this still wasn't the case.

Comment: I think I might just use `localStorage` for this

Answer (score 3):

So it appears to be the expiration causing the issue. As of AngularJS 1.2.19, you are not able to set the expiration date through `$cookie` or `$cookieStore`.

To remedy this, I used local storage instead. I used this module to give easy access to local storage: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

It was pretty painless to change. I changed `$cookieStore.get('remember');` to `localStorageService.get('remember');` so as you can see they share method names. Instead of `put`, it's `add`