# Angular and $cookies - $cookies.get is not a function

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use cookies within Angular - here's what I'm trying:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>

var capApp = angular.module('capApp', ['ngRoute','ui.bootstrap','ngCookies']);

capApp.controller('cookieCtrl', ['$scope','$cookies', function($scope, $cookies) {
  var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('user_id');
  alert(favoriteCookie);
}]);
```

I get this error in the console:

```
TypeError: $cookies.get is not a function
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

**UPDATE**

Check which version of Angular you are using for everything - any Angular guys read this, make the version switch in the docs bright green and huge! You simply don't notice it.

Comment: because you use `$cookieStore` not `$cookie`, edit: oops my bad, deprecated now edit2: but still, there is no `get()` on `$cookies` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: Nope, $cookieStore is deprecated - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore

Comment: damn, I'm all over the place, lol. There is a get(). welp leme see...

Comment: Please read this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies - put writes, get reads

Comment: ok, I got it. The problem is I was looking at 1.4.0 docs and 1.3.14 docs. The version you are using does NOT have get(). get() was introduced in 1.4.0. I knew I wasn't going crazy

Comment: Aaahhhh - I never even noticed the version switch in the top left corner - Angular seems great but a lot of messing about with versions - code changes every week!

Comment: I'm still using 1.3.x as well. I also started using https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage over cookies because I couldn't get cookies to persist over sessions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702432/angularjs-cookies-are-not-persisting

Comment: Thanks, will take a look at that - might close this question

Comment: I'd leave it open, help some poor soul in the near future

Comment: Thank god for finding this, I love you all

Comment: Holy crap. Thanks for leaving this open!

Comment: This just saved my sanity.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In Angular 1.3.14 you can just use

```
var favoriteCookie = $cookies[user_id];
```

See the documentaiton here: [Angular Cookies](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Comment: This doesn't work any more in Angular 1.4.x. From the Angular wesbite: BREAKING CHANGE: $cookies no longer exposes properties that represent the current browser cookie values. Now you must use the get/put/remove/etc. methods as described below. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies)

Answer (score 11):

The syntax you have is for version 1.4.x but you are referencing an older version. If you do not want to update to 1.4.x, you can use $cookieStore instead as follows:

```
$cookieStore.put("key", "value"); 
var value = $cookieStore.get("key");
```

Alternatively if you are using version 1.3.x or below, you can use $cookies as  follows:

```
$cookies.key = "value";
var value = $cookies.key;
```

Answer (score 2):

The following method should work.

```
var favoriteCookie = $cookies.user_id;
```