# Unable to store cookies in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a small project in [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/) in which I am trying to store username and password into browser cookies.

here is my app.js code. you can see that I have injected ngCookies as dependency injection.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'myApp.routes', 'ngCookies']);
```

following is my login Controller.

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', function($scope, loginService) {

    $scope.login=function(user){
        loginService.login(user);
    }

});
```

and here is my service which is calling data for authentication

```
app.factory('loginService', function($http, $state, $cookies){
    return{
        login:function(user){
            var storedUser = $http.get('data/user.json').
                success(function(data) {

                if(user.email === data.email && user.password === data.password ){
                    //var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('userEmail');
                    $cookies.put("userEmail", user.email);
                    $cookies.put("password", user.password);    
                    $state.go('dashboard', {});
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid Username or Password");
                }

                })
            }
        }
});
```

when I run my project I am getting this error. **$cookies.put is not a function** in console.

*note: Version of AngularJs and Angular-cookies are AngularJS v1.2.28*

Comment: I had a similar question - take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971126/angular-and-cookies-cookies-get-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use `$cookieStore` instead of `$cookies`

Try this

```
app.factory('loginService', function($http, $state, $cookieStore){
    return{
        login:function(user){
            var storedUser = $http.get('data/user.json').
                success(function(data) {

                if(user.email === data.email && user.password === data.password ){
                    //var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('userEmail');
                    $cookieStore.put("userEmail", user.email);
                    $cookieStore.put("password", user.password);    
                    $state.go('dashboard', {});
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid Username or Password");
                }

                })
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: any specific reason behind using $cookieStore and not $ngCookies ?, as I read on angularJs site that Note: The $cookieStore service is deprecated. Please use the $cookies service instead.

Comment: @NileshMahajan If you look at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngCookies/cookieStore.js#L36 you'll see a `factory` inside of `ngCookies` model.

Comment: $cookieStore has been deprecated in favor of $cookie

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$cookie.put`

```
var userdetails = { userEmail: user.email, password: user.password };

$cookies.UserDetails = angular.toJson(userdetails);
```