# How do I use ngCookies with AngularJS login controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-cookies

I've used generator-angular-fullstack with a freshly made route client/app/login. It contains login.controller.js, login.html, login.js, login.controller.spec.js and login.scss. I've set up a sign-in API endpoint
I would like to save "authentication_token" and "user_id" from the JSON it returns to a cookie. Angular-cookies (ngCookies) is installed.

I've tried adapting the documentation examples (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies), but not much luck so far. **Console error = '$cookies.put is not a function'** (Angular 1.5.6). Also, changing

```
angular.module('myApp');
```

to

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
```

or even

```
angular.module('myApp', ['']);
```

already makes the login page go blank, except for the header. I don't think it's matter of the module not existing, since trying to load a non-existing module gives a completely blank page (no header either).

Any suggestions?

**login.html**

```
<body>
<script src="/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>    
<form ng-submit="callSignIn(username, password, site)">
Email:
  <input type="text" ng-model="username"><br>
Password:
  <input type="text" ng-model="password"><br>
Site:
  <input type="text" ng-model="site"><br>
  <input type="submit" value= "Submit">
</form>
<section ui-view>Response: {{response}}</section>
</body>
```

**login.controller.js**

```
'use strict';
(function(){

  class LoginComponent {
    constructor($scope, $http, $cookies) {
      $scope.callSignIn = function(username, password, site) {
        $http.post('/api/auth/signin', {
          username: username,
          password: password,
          site: site
        }).success(function(response, $cookies) {
          $scope.response = response;
          $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal'); //testvalue
        });
      };

    }
  }

  angular.module('orbitApp') //angular.module('orbitApp', ['ngCookies']) gives blank login page...
    .component('login', {
      templateUrl: 'app/login/login.html',
      controller: LoginComponent
    });

})();
```

login.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('orbitApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        template: '<login></login>'
      });
  });
```

**Typical JSON response:**

```
{"http_code":200,"response":{"authentication_token":"a","site_id":"b","content_url":"c","user_id":"d"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you loading `angular-cookies.js` in login.html and not your index.html.

By the time your module bootstraps, `angular-cookies` is not available to you making it go blank, you could have a `console error too`.

Comment: I should have added the console error yes, and probably the Angular version I'm using. Question edited to include those.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28971126/angular-and-cookies-cookies-get-is-not-a-function

Comment: Yes I read that answer before posting. That's also why I just included the Angular version: 1.5 > 1.4, hence $cookies.put should work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing

```
.success(function(response, $cookies) {
```

to

```
.success(function(response) {
```

while keeping everything else the same (incl. angular.module). It works like a charm now.