# With 1.4 version of AngularJS, is it possible to create persistent cookies with $cookies?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, persistent, cookiestore

With 1.4 version of AngularJS, is it possible to create persistent cookies with `$cookies`?

I want data to be stored once I login, for 7 days say. In version 1.3.X, it is not possible to set Expiration date even. But with 1.4, they have deprecated `$cookieStore` and set an option in `$cookies` for expiration date.

I want to know whether this one creates cookies for desired longer periods rather than I close the browser and everything is gone.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702432/angularjs-cookies-are-not-persisting

Comment: Do you really want to use cookies? Unless you need this info on every http request, I think local storage is a better option. A nice library is [here](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage) and it works with 1.4

Comment: You can not set the expiration date using localStorage.

Comment: I think document.cookie is working

Answer (score 2):

You can set the expires property on the `$cookiesProvider` to change the default behaviour of the `$cookies` service. `$cookiesProvider` is available with version 1.4.  For more info, see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider#defaults).

Comment: I think $cookiesProvider is available in 1.3.X also. Now, Suppose I logged in and it creates a cookie with expires set to 7 days +current time. If I shut down my browser and start again, will it be there? OR is it like, maximum period of cookie is 7 days and if you shut down it ll be deleted OR if you are logged in, it ll stay for max 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

The code below do what you want. When you are writing the cookie you can [tell the expiration date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/provider/$cookiesProvider). You can close the browser and the cookie will remain active.

> Setting expiry dates PREVENT it from being deleted when the browser is closed.
>   [setting persistent cookies with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733025/setting-persistent-cookies-with-javascript#comment10875843_8733025)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="cookiesExample">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.2/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <script>
        angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
      .controller('MainCtrl', ['$cookies', '$scope', function($cookies, $scope) {
        // Retrieving a cookie
        var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');

        $scope.name = (favoriteCookie) ? 'welcome back' : 'first time';
        // Setting a cookie

        var now = new Date();
        now.setDate(now.getDate() + 7);
        $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal', {
          expires: now
        });

      }]);
    </script>
  </body>


</html>
```