# REST Authentication using AngularJs with Yii2

Tags: angularjs, rest, cordova, ionic-framework, yii2

I'm a building a simple PhoneGap app with Ionic framework and for the back-end I'm using Yii2.

The app is working cool, I'm making requests to get some data from the server and etc...

The problem is, I want to authenticate my users from a database and dont allow using the app without authentication, but the problem is that I'm pretty new to angular and the restfull thing.

I searched and read bunch of articles about authentication via rest api but I could not imagine how things fit together.

So can someone give me some good articles or tutorials which will guide me in this long road? :)

OR

Someone has a working example of authentication with tokens with yii2 and angularjs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only give you some links,maybe it can help.

[githubjeka/angular-yii2](https://github.com/githubjeka/angular-yii2)

And you should check this too.

[guide-rest-authentication](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-authentication.html)

Answer (score 0):

**RESTful Links.**
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21258/Everything-about-REST-web-services-what-and-how

https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/11/a-restful-learning-curve-nouns-verbs-hateoas-and-roca/

http://www.slideshare.net/mario_cardinal/best-practices-for-designing-pragmatic-restful-api

**Angular Authentication Link.**

[angular auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27476336/howto-angularjs-basic-auth-cookie-to-a-rest-api-server)

Hope it helps: