# Storing persistent cookies with angular

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I would like to know how can I store cookies with Angular. I want my cookies to be persistent so that when the browser is closed, I can still access them.

I want to store language preferences on the clients computer.

I already tried `$cookies` and `$cookieStore` but they only seem to work for the current session. When the browser is reopened, no data is found.

So how can I store persistent cookies with angular?

I have this example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/krimple/9dSb2/) and it has the same behavior in Chrome and FF.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624181/angularjs-how-to-set-expiration-date-for-cookie-in-angularjs.  You might consider using localStorage as well.