# What would prevent AngularJS $cookies from writing a cookie?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

I'm attempting to write a simple cookie using the AngularJS v1.5.x [$cookies](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.4/docs/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) service. The dependencies are all correct, as I can read a cookie. However, neither write nor edit are working.

For example:

```
var blah = $cookies.get('mysite_auth');
console.log('old: ' + blah);

$cookies.put('mysite_auth', 'blech');

blah = $cookies.get('mysite_auth');
console.log('new: ' + blah);
```

... results in the following output:

> old: ZmVhZDE ... =
>   new: ZmVhZDE ... =

No errors are thrown. The same occurs when attempting to write a new cookie:

```
$cookies.put('someCookie', 'yup');
```

I can write a cookie in my controller like so:

```
document.cookie = 'TEST=TESTVALUE';
```

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: It might fail on older versions of IE. What browsers are you trying this on?

Comment: Chrome latest stable.

Comment: have you tried $cookieStore.put to put values  ?

Comment: No. My understanding is that `$cookieStore` is deprecated.

Comment: I found this issue on GitHub that mentions `$cookie.put` works asynchronously. You might be reading the cookie before it's actually written. You can try setting a timeout to see if that's the case. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6411

Comment: Cookies don't appear in dev tools at all. I've used jQuery to write cookies before and am familiar with typical behavior.

Comment: are you finding any difference between localhost and other dev environments as that's come up before?

Comment: Here's something odd: This doesn't work in a local HTML file, but it does on JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/9nnypax5

Comment: If it's a local file, then you probably need to start Chrome with an extra flag if you want cookies to work. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/347997/1789724.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that Angular $cookies was writing the cookie, but we had a domain/path problem. Because our Angular apps live outside our back end app directory, the page URL doesn't match the server path. If I visited the actual path, while the page didn't properly load, the cookie was present.

We resolved the issue with this domain/path configuration:

```
$cookies.put('myCookie', true, {
    domain: '.mydomain.com',
    path: currentUrl,
    expires: exp
});
```

Answer (score -1):

have you tried setting the expiration for your cookie?

e.g.

```
var dDate = new $window.Date(),
var dExp = new $window.Date(dDate.getFullYear(), dDate.getMonth()+1, dDate.getDate());

$cookies.put('someCookie','yup', {expires: dExp});

var cCookie = $cookies.get('someCookie');
console.log(cCookie);
```

just found a cookie thread actually which might help: [How to set expiration date for cookie in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624181/how-to-set-expiration-date-for-cookie-in-angularjs)

Comment: I have. I removed it to simplify troubleshooting. That property is not required.