# cookieStore and cookies not working in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am currently using version `1.2.28` of AngularJS and am having issues setting and retrieving cookies.

Here's a code snippet:

```
administrators.createNewAdministrator($stateParams.code).then(
    function (response) {
        $cookies.name = 'Rafael';
        $cookieStore.put('name', 'Rafael');
        var url = url.getRedirectURL(window.location.origin, response.code);
        window.location.href = url;
    }
);
```

Opening the `Application => Cookies` pane does not show any of the cookies using either of these methods.

Any ideas as to what may be causing this?

Comment: The first thing I observe here is that you create a url variable, which depends on itself. Do you have any errors in your console if you temporarily remove the line window.location.href = url; ?

Comment: @LajosArpad, no. Actually, even if I remove those last 2 lines and only keep the cookie logic, the issue persists.

Comment: I was asking specifically about any errors you receive in your browser's console. Removing the redirect was meant to allow you to see the error messages, not to fix the problem. First let's see what the problem is and only then fix it.

Comment: @LajosArpad, good point. There are no Console errors showing up.

Comment: If you put a console.log at the top of your function, like console.log('The function is running'); do you see it in the console?

Comment: @LajosArpad, yes, I do see that. If it helps, this is the only function inside of my `$scope.init = function() { ... }`. I also tried removing the lines outside of this function and the issue remains.

Comment: After you set the cookie values how did you try to access them?

Comment: Should I not be able to see them in the cookies pane in the Dev Tools?

Comment: The best way to check is to run document.cookie in your console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167470/discussion-between-user-5842-and-lajos-arpad).

Answer (score 0):

For a cookie to be persistent over browser sessions, the expiration date should be set. Unfortunately, this does not seem to be supported with the angularjs $cookie service. See this post

[How to set expiration date for cookie in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624181/how-to-set-expiration-date-for-cookie-in-angularjs)

Check the above post if still the issue doesn't solve then check weather redirecting to a particular url is clearing the cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’ll look into this, but even without doing the redirect, the cookies are not being set. I cannot access them through the cookies pane in the Dev Tools

Comment: I'm not sure I'm able to use the `expiry` in my version of Angular @Neha Tawar