# How to set cookie with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cookies

I trying to set a cookie following [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624181/how-to-set-expiration-date-for-cookie-in-angularjs). However I must have missed something fundamental as the console only returns undefined. Here is the full html content.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular-cookies.js"></script>

<script>
    angular.module('App', ['ngCookies'])
    .controller('ctrl', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
        $cookies.put('token', 'Test', {'expires': 'Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59'});
        console.log($cookies.get('token'));
    }]);
</script>

</head>
<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="ctrl"></body>
</html>
```

For the off-case it matters: Chromium 65 on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit). Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong in your code with the way to set cookies. Actually `Chrome` ignores cookies from `local pages` but other browsers like safari will satisfy you with it's execution. If you upload the page to `remote server`, it will work for chromium.
So It is better use `localStorage` instead of `cookies` in your case.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. For more "Reasons": https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=535