# Jasmine and angularjs, using $cookies in jasmine

Tags: cookies, jasmine

I am fairly new to jasmine and wanted to create a test for the following below, I created the code in the test section but I get "TypeError: Cannot set property 'username' of undefined"..

I created a global namespace 'cp' in apps.js and used that in the service and controller.

```
//controller
cp.controller = {};
cp.controller.LoginController = function($scope, $location, $cookies){
        $scope.signIn = function(){
            $cookies.user = $scope.form.username;
            user.set($scope.form.username);
            $location.hash( "home" );
        }
};
//service 
cp.serviceFactory = {};
cp.serviceFactory.user = function user( $cookies){
    var userName = $cookies.user;
    return{
        set: function(name){
            userName = name;
        },
        get: function(){
            return userName;
        }
    }
};
//test script
describe('Cameo Controllers', function() {

    describe('LoginController', function(){
        var scope, cookies, ctrl, $httpBackend;
        beforeEach(module('CameoPaaS'));
        beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller, $cookies) {
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
           // cookies =  $cookies.username;
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            cookies = scope.$cookies;
            ctrl = $controller(cp.controller.LoginController, {$scope: scope, $cookies: cookies});
        }));
        it('should log the user into the system', function() {
            expect(scope.username).toBeUndefined();
            scope.form.username = 'me';
            scope.signIn();
            //expect(user).toBe(undefined);
        });
    });
});
```

Question: how do I define and set the value for the $cookies.username in the test script to get around the error.

Answer (score 2):

First off make sure you are including angular-cookies.js these were separated from main distro in [1.0.0rc3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100rc3-barefoot-telepathy-2012-03-29)

If it were me, I would wrap the cookies handling into a service and then use jasmine to mock/spy on the your cookie-wrapper service implementation. You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961963/how-to-access-cookies-in-angularjs) helpful. Also, I found this [testing cookies in unit and e2e](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/qLA8ishtpGk). IMHO the problem with this is that it is too close to the metal, having to work with the browser cookies directly.

Answer (score 2):

I also run through the same problem, here is the workaround -

```
beforeEach(inject(function($cookies){
    $cookies.username = 'AngularJs'; 
}));
```

Please suggest if there is any better way.