# Setting cookie from WebApi via angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm making a call to the WebApi service, which sets the cookie in the response object.
The call is made from angularjs via $resource
So this is the server code:

```
CookieHeaderValue cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("Token", "blah") { HttpOnly = true, Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10), Path="/"  };
response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
```

This works, I can see the Set-Cookie header in a response, however the cookie is not being set.

A friend of mine had to set  xhrFields' withCredentials to true when he was using jQuery, so I wonder if there's something that needs to be configured in angular as well ?

Comment: Is the api on the same domain as the page making the request?

Comment: No, different domains.

Comment: @Evgeni did you got the answer? because i'm stuck in the same situation.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a number of things going on.

First, since you are on separate domains, you may need to implement [CORs (cross origin resource sharing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but it seems that the request is being made successfully.  I'm not sure why that works, I would think that browsers would prevent it.  In any case here's a [jsfiddle that illustrates using CORs with angularjs to make both $http & $resource](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardohbin/E3YEt/) requests. The trick seems to be to configure the $http service:

```
 $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;
```

Another thought is that cookies from one domain, can't be accessed by another domain.  Here is another [question on cookies with angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961963/how-to-access-cookies-in-angularjs), but the request and server seem to be on the same domain.  Here is a discussion on [cookie domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062963/how-do-browser-cookie-domains-work), and how they are applied.

If it's possible I would try to get the cookie request/response working on the same domain, and then move the client to another domain.

Comment: According to this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/kl2BVOubG4I - there's no such option as useXDomain. Tried it anyway, didn't make a difference. Also, I should've made myself more clear - although the client sits on a different domain, it is a server setting and reading the cookie, so CORS should be irrelevant in this case, I think. It is an ajax call, but from a browser point of view this makes no difference, afaik.