# How do you test AngularJS cookies in an end-to-end test?

Tags: testing, angularjs, end-to-end

I have a simple service that sets cookies in angular, but there's no obvious way to test that they've been set in an end-to-end test.

The code to test is as simple as

```
var splashApp = angular.module('splashApp', ['ngCookies']);
splashApp.controller('FooterController', function ($location, $cookies) {
    $cookies.some_cookie = $location.absUrl();
});
```

But I can't find any docs on how to test. Here's what I have found:

- [How to access cookies in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961963/how-to-access-cookies-in-angularjs)
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookies
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies.$cookieStore

I've also tried

```
angular.scenario.dsl('cookies', function() {
  var chain = {};
  chain.get = function(name) {
    return this.addFutureAction('get cookies', function($window, $document, done) {
      var injector = $window.angular.element($window.document.body).inheritedData('$injector');
      var cookies = injector.get('$cookies');
      done(null, cookies);
    });
  };
  return function() {
    return chain;
  }
});
```

But this returns only the cookies for the parent browser, not the page I want to test.

Any examples on how to do this?

Comment: I'd assume that you're doing something with the cookies, maybe changing a CSS class, in your program - anything that effectively binds the value of the cookie to something external. Try testing that instead?

Comment: I'm not, actually. The cookies are stored at some point in the session, then they're sent (automatically) to the server along with a  POST request. There's no UI change because of cookies, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you read this? http://pastie.org/4758669

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use [PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-Reference).

> PhantomJS is a headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API. It
>   has fast and native support for various web standards: DOM handling,
>   CSS selector, JSON, Canvas, and SVG. --[PhantomJS website](http://phantomjs.org/)

It has support for custom cookies in its API.
In terms of testing, this is probably your best choice.
You might also want to look at [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) to help test page navigation.