# How to set cookie in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angularjs-scope, angular-cookies

I am developing a simple web application using angularjs. The application logs in using Facebook connect and then lists data.

I am able to login using Facebook but I don't know how to use $cookie for the web app and access that.

Can anyone can explain how to do that?

I am using the 'ngCookies' module.

Here is the code :

```
myapp.controller('CookieController', [ '$scope', '$cookies', '$cookieStore',
    function($scope, $cookies, $cookieStore) {
        $scope.setCookie = function(key, value) {
            $cookieStore.put(key, value);
            $cookies.first_name = value;
        };
        $scope.getCookie = function(key) {
            return $cookieStore.get(key);
        };

        $scope.doLogin = function() {
            $scope.setCookie("loggedin", "true");
        };

        $scope.doLogout = function() {
            $scope.setCookie("loggedin", "");
        };
    } ]);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961963/how-to-access-cookies-in-angularjs