# Cookies in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, cookies

I am making a SPA. On successful login I set the `cookies(username,userid,etc.)` that contain user information getting from the api.

**Set a cookie using PHP :**

```
setcookie("NAME",$records['userinfo']['name'],time()+(20 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
```

**Get it using JavaScript :**

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

**Try to show in Controller :**

```
angular.module('App', [])

  .controller('UserProfileCtrl', function($scope) {
     function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
 $scope.username = getCookie('NAME');
  })
```

**index.html :**

```
<html data-ng-app="App" data-ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body data-ng-class="{'skip-animations':disabled}" class="ng-cloak">
        <div class="list-group" data-ng-controller="UserProfileCtrl">
       <p>Welcome</p>
        <div class="username">{{username}}</div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 user">
        <div class="user-bg-image">
        <img src="images/user-bg.png">
        <div class="user-img"><img src="{{userimage}}">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="user-profile clearfix">
        <a href="#123"><li>Edit Profile</li></a>
        <a href="#123" onclick="logout()"><li>Logout</li></a>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works fine with reloading the app.On reloading we are able to retrieve cookie data (`username`).

**Problem :**

How can we retrieve these cookies without reloading the app?

Comment: simply call cookie retrival method whenever you want..

Comment: @pankajparkar, it works fine with reloading the page where i want to show the cookie data.But the problem is that i want to show data on the same page without reloading

Comment: @pankajparkar, So, you have any idea how can i do that using angular..I am using angular to make SPA.so want to access cookie data without reloading the page,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies), is the best way, and in case that you want to persist that data in any part of the DOM, use `$cookieStore`

anyways, here are the differences

`$cookieStore`

> Provides a key-value (string-object) storage, that is backed by session cookies. Objects put or retrieved from this storage are automatically serialized or deserialized by angular's toJson/fromJson.

`$cookies`

> Provides read/write access to browser's cookies.

Usage, parting from @Dan Doyon [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961963/how-to-access-cookies-in-angularjs)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyController">

  <h3>Cookies</h3>
  <pre>{{usingCookies|json}}</pre>
  <h3>Cookie Store</h3>
  <pre>{{usingCookieStore|json}}</pre>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular-cookies.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
    app.controller('MyController',['$scope','$cookies','$cookieStore', 
                       function($scope,$cookies,$cookieStore) {
      var someSessionObj = { 'innerObj' : 'somesessioncookievalue'};

    $cookies.dotobject = someSessionObj;
    $scope.usingCookies = { 'cookies.dotobject' : $cookies.dotobject, "cookieStore.get" : $cookieStore.get('dotobject') };

    $cookieStore.put('obj', someSessionObj);
    $scope.usingCookieStore = { "cookieStore.get" : $cookieStore.get('obj'), 'cookies.dotobject' : $cookies.obj, };
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and remember

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
```

**UPDATE**

as per @lucky7id comments, he is right, `$cookieStore` is deprecated, so just keep using `$cookies` which is almost the same.

Comment: `$cookieStore` is deprecated :/

Comment: I think its `$cookies` now https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: @lucky7id I am currently using ```$cookieStore``` in a mobile app I am developing.

Comment: @TheUnnamed it's deprecated past 1.3.x, just depends on which version of the docs you look at.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [ngCookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies), it does a lot of this work for you, including session cookies.

Also, upon successful login, you may want to simply write the cookie in JS, in your callback.

Comment: i am doing same as suggest by you.cookie is write in JS perfectly but how to show it in same page using angular.

Comment: The `$cookies` service has the `get()` and `getObject()` methods, you simply pass the key you stored the cookie as to the appropriate method.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: I passed but how can i show it to the user without refreshing the app.

Comment: @RohitJindal Can you update your post to show where you have added the $scope bindings, and corresponding markup?