# Losing Cookies when navigating to a new page in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I am trying to develop 2 pages:

Page 1: Normal Login Page login.html
Page 2: Home Page home.html

I am using AngularJS to code the scripts in these pages.

I have to transfer some data between these two pages. So i decided to use cookies (I tried to use Services but i didn't know how to write the same service for 2 separate files).

In the Login page i saved the cookies as follow :

```
    var resultObj = {'loginid',result};
    $cookies.dotobject = resultObj;
    window.location = 'Home.html';
```

I checked that this cookie is saved correctly (Console.log(resultObj))

However when i open the home page i try to read this cookie using:

```
   var result = $cookies.dotobject;
   console.log(result) //To check if it worked
```

But it didn't, i got undefined.

My question is can I use $cookies in this case ? And why does it disappear ?

If cookies are not useful in this case how to use a service between 2 different pages containing 2 different controllers ?

Excuse me if this questions aren't from a good quality since i am still learning these concepts.

**EDIT**

I tried to write in the same document :

```
    console.log(result);
    $cookies.put('loginid',result);
    var loginida = $cookies.get('loginid');
    console.log(loginida);
```

But the $cookies.get does not work ; It gives also undefined . Any ideas ?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the correct way to use `$cookies` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies

Comment: I used the code suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961963/how-to-access-cookies-in-angularjs , i will check the documentation now and try again

Comment: what version of angular? Are you working with object? Using service or localStorage would be better if so

Comment: In the first example i was using angular 1.2.19 (as suggested in the link)
In the second i was using 1.4.8 (as in the documentation)

Comment: To solve the problem i used localStorage as charlietfl suggested, and it works exactly as needed. Thanks