# Remember comments information with cookies angular

Tags: angularjs, cookies

My Review book doesn't have login. When a user submits comment form (name, surname, email, review), I want to use cookies so that when he goes to All reviews list, he would be able to edit/delete it's posts without login. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Of course. That is what [$cookies](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies) is for.

For a complete example check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10985815/5739073

Comment: Yes, but you should probably have flag this as a duplicate instead of answering.

Comment: That's what I will do next time. Thanks.

Comment: @Mistalis Apparently I can't flag because I don't have enough privileges.

Comment: The question has already been closed