# Angular checkbox need to be checked on UI all the time whenever I try to login or reopen the browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs

html:

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="Values" selected-model="modelSelected" extra-settings="multiselectSettings" translation-texts="someCustomTexts" checkboxes="true" events="updateMultiEvents"></div>
```

js:

```
$scope.values = someData[];
$scope.modelSelected=[];
```

I have selected this checkbox earlier and stored model value in cookie. When i login again, all the time, this checkbox should be checked. Any idea?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! The code you shared doesn't seem to be enough for us to see what's wrong. You should share the code where you read the cookie you have set previously and give the model its value (if not done, you should give a try and share specific issues here, if you have some). Sharing the part where the cookie is set could be useful too.

Comment: Writing cookie using jquery:
$.cookie("modelSelected", $scope.modelSelected, { expires: 60});


Reading cookie using jquery:
$.cookie('modelSelected')


When this cookie is present for the particular model, that checkbox should be selected.How could we do that in html/angualar/jquery

Answer (score 0):

the checkbox isn't selected because you haven't assign the cookies value to your current value.
example:
$scope.modelSelected = $cookieStore.get('your_stored_var_name');

Comment: $scope.modelSelected = $.cookie('modelSelected')...tried this...but it was showing as undefined and drop down shows 15 services got selected but checkboxes are not showing as seected..when i try to check the checkbox throws modelSelected.push is not a function

Comment: Have you tried to $apply() after setting the cookie ?

Comment: your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961963/how-to-access-cookies-in-angularjs?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I just put sample in jsfiddle...could you please check this one https://jsfiddle.net/yk6bnsjz/

Comment: I see, $ is not defined, add jquery librery, example: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script> in you html

Comment: its already been added in my actual code.I just given sample logic